# Explicit Wait PageFactory @Findby

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wait, factory

I have this wait command in Java with a css locator, and then clicks on it.

```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.md-primary.md-raised.md-button.md-default-theme"))).click();
```

Now I turned that locator into a pagefactory object which is `lp.btnSignIn()` what would be the proper way to issue this explicit wait and then click? Can I still use expected conditions?

This is my PageFactory Code:

```
@FindBy(css="button.md-primary.md-raised.md-button.md-default-theme")
WebElement btnSignIn;

public WebElement btnSignIn() {
    return btnSignIn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing to VisibilityOf:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(lp.btnSignIn())).click();
```

Be careful though as this checks if the element is visible, which it might not be, but it is still in a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on what your lp.btnSignIn() method is returning.

Quoting from the selenium documentation [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)
```

An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

**Parameters:**

**locator** - used to find the element

**Returns:**
    the WebElement once it is located

Hence you could use lp.btnSignIn() only if it's returning the css locater in place of WebElement

Hence your btnSignIn() methos would something like this:

```
public static Locater btnSignIn() {
    return By.cssSelector("button.md-primary.md-raised.md-button.md-default-theme");
}
```

And now your could use the Expected conditions as below:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(lp.btnSignIn())).click()`;
```

Comment: it's returning a css locator. What is the proper syntax to insert my WebElement?

Comment: Hi, I see it the problem is my object is a WebElement not a Locater. See my edited code. Thanks

Comment: You can't use presenceOfElementLocatedBy you will have to use some toher expected condition but it wouldnt do the same